# SQL*Plus does not open anymore - Oracle Database 18c Express Edition

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle18c

I have been using Oracle 18c since March for my college classes. I have always worked using SQLplus. The issue now is that I cannot start SQL*Plus when I tried to start it 2 days before.

When I try to launch it, it opens and closes in less than a second. I tried to open sqlplus via command prompt, but it shows an error saying:

> Error 57 initializing SQL*Plus Error loading message shared library

I have no clue what went wrong so I thought re-installing the entire 18c product would solve something. Now that I go for uninstalling Oracle 18c, it shows an error message like shown here

[image]

Can someone please suggest me what is going wrong here? I would really like to have the SQLPlus working again like normally it would, so I can complete my DBMS projects.

Comment: Have you tried running as admin? `runas /user:Administrator "msiexec /x {C220B7FD-3095-47FC-A0C0-AE49DE6E320A}"`

Comment: @kfinity hey there! I tried the command you sent but it shows me the same "error 1723" I have shown in the image attached to my post.